# TypeError - Classes in Python

Tags: python, class, typeerror

I'm a beginner at Python just getting to grips with classes. I'm sure it's probably something very basic, but why does this code:

```
class Television():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Welcome your TV.')
        self.volume = 10
        self.channel = 1
    def channel(self, channel):
        self.channel = input('Pick a channel: ')
        print('You are on channel ' + self.channel)
    def volume_up(self, amount):
        self.amount = ('Increase the volume by: ')
        self.volume += self.amount
        print('The volume is now ' + self.volume)
    def volume_down(self, amount):
        self.amount = ('Decrease the volume by: ')
        self.volume -= self.amount
        print('The volume is now ' + self.volume)
myTele = Television()
myTele.channel()
myTele.volume_up()
myTele.volume_down()
```

Produce the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable, Line 18
```

**EDIT**: I changed the code to this:

```
class Television():
    def __init__(self, volume = 10, channel = 1):
        print('Welcome your TV.')
        self.volume = volume
        self.channel = channel
    def change(self, channel):
        self.channel = input('Pick a channel: ')
        print('You are on channel ' + self.channel)
    def volume_up(self, amount):
        self.amount = int(input('Increase the volume by: '))
        self.volume += self.amount
        print('The volume is now ' + str(self.volume))
    def volume_down(self, amount):
        self.amount = int(input('Decrease the volume by: '))
        self.volume -= self.amount
        print('The volume is now ' + str(self.volume))
myTele = Television()
myTele.change()
myTele.volume_up()
myTele.volume_down()
```

But it returns:

```
TypeError: change() missing 1 required positional argument: 'channel'
```

Again, this is coming from someone just starting with classes, so please don't be too harsh if I've done something glaringly obvious wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You assign a `channel` attribute in your `__init__`:

```
self.channel = 1
```

This shadows the `channel()` method on the class. Rename the attribute or the method.

Attributes on the instance trump those on the class (except for data descriptors; think `property`s). From the [Class definitions documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions):

> Variables defined in the class definition are class attributes; they are shared by instances. Instance attributes can be set in a method with `self.name = value`. Both class and instance attributes are accessible through the notation “`self.name`”, and an instance attribute hides a class attribute with the same name when accessed in this way.

Your methods also expect a parameter that you are not passing in in your example, but I'm figuring you'll solve that yourself next.

Comment: Martijn, how good are you? I mean every time I open up a Python question you're first to the punch :)

Comment: @MorganWilde: you are right .. i agree. ..  !! indeed his answers are great source of learning :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a method called `channel` and a variable called `channel`.  The variable, which is an `int`, shadows the method (steals it's name so that you can't access it).  Rename wither the method or the variable and this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code after the Edit exposed the problem Martijn was already indicating at. Your `self.change()` expects a parameter which you don't provide in `myTele.change()`. Since you are not using the parameter in the method, you should define `change` as:

```
def change(self):
    self.channel = input('Pick a channel: ')
    print('You are on channel ' + self.channel)
```

`volume_up` and `volume_down` actually assign a string to self.amount instead of calling a function. You probably want to change those to

```
def volume_up(self, amount):
    self.amount = input('Increase the volume by: ')
    self.volume += self.amount
    print('The volume is now ' + self.volume)
def volume_down(self, amount):
    self.amount = input('Decrease the volume by: ')
    self.volume -= self.amount
    print('The volume is now ' + self.volume)
```

Since you are setting `self.amount` every time before using it, you can probably just make it a local variable to the method ( `amount` ). If you have future plans to have a method `xyz()` that uses `self.amount` without first setting it, you should make sure `self.amount` is set in `__init__()` to a reasonable value, in case `xyz()` is called before the volume changing methods.

Comment: Thanks, you cleared up what Martijn was saying about passing parameters in methods.

Comment: You were lucky I came in late to this question and noticed your edit, such a late change with additional things to be answered often gets unnoticed.