# TypeError: Python ask to insert self argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, typeerror

I'm working on my own version of the module `logging`, I'm almost finished with the base, but I get an error that I cant solve on my own.

I tried looking at others questions on so, but nothing helped me.
(Other questions I looked at: [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55770064/python-typeerror-listen-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self) - [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668246/typeerror-classes-in-python) - [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions))
The full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\server.py", line 20, in <module>
    debugger.status(True)
TypeError: status() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inp'
```

and my code:

```
class debugger():
    def __init__(self, state=False):
        self.state = state

    def status(self, inp:bool):
        if inp == True and self.state == False: print('Debugger activated')
        elif inp == True and self.state == True: print('Debugger alredy started')
        elif inp == False and self.state == True: print('Debugger stopped')
        else: print('Debugger alredy stopped')
        self.state = inp

    def log(self, msg:str):
        if self.state == True: print(f'[DEBUGGER]: {msg}')
        else: pass

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.state == True: return 'Debugger status: Active'
        else: return 'Debugger status: Disabled'

debugger.status(True)
debugger()
debugger.log('Test from debugger')
```

**EDIT:**
If i try to change the 3 lines at the bottom to:

```
debugger.status(debugger, True)
debugger()
debugger.log(debugger, 'Test from debugger')
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\server.py", line 22, in <module>
    debugger.status(debugger, True)
  File ".\server.py", line 8, in status
    if inp == True and self.state == False: print('Debugger activated')
AttributeError: type object 'debugger' has no attribute 'state'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call both methods on an *instance* of the class, not the class itself.

```
d = debugger()
d.status(True)
d.log('Test from debugger')
```

Comment: well, I'm starting to think that I need to sleep more... Thanks